# How to get the weight vector in Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a X feature matrix and a y label matrix and I am using binary logistic regression how can I get the weight vector w given matrix X feature and Y label matrix. I am a bit confused as to how achieve this within sklean.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 20):

If i understand correctly you are looking for [the `coef_` attribute](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

```
lr = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
lr.fit(X, Y)

print(lr.coef_) # returns a matrix of weights (coefficients)
```

The shape of `coef_` attribute should be: (`# of classes`, `# of features`)

If you also need an intercept (AKA bias) column, then use this:

```
np.hstack((clf.intercept_[:,None], clf.coef_))
```

this will give you an array of shape: (`n_classes`, `n_features + 1`)

Comment: What is default value for bias and weights?

Answer (score -1):

```
clf_bow_perb = LogisticRegression(C= 10, penalty= 'l2')
clf_bow_perb.fit(X_1,y_1)
y_pred = clf_bow_perb.predict(X_1)
print("Accuracy on test set: %0.3f%%"%(accuracy_score(y_1, y_pred)*100))
print("Non Zero weights:",np.count_nonzero(clf.coef_))
```